# Can a balanced internal force and unbalanced internal force cause motion?

Tags: forces, kinematics

Can an internal balanced force cause motion in a (any) object when applied.

Answer (score 1):

> Can an internal balanced force cause motion in a (any) object when
>   applied.

Balanced internal forces cannot move the center of mass of an object, but they could stretch or shrink objects (like in a bow) or cause parts of an object move, e.g. rotate, relative to each other (like in a motor).

Comment: I think you gotta write one balanced and other unbalanced internal force instead of balanced internal force.

Comment: I think the author has asked about the case that an object has one balanced and other unbalanced force then can that move. So perfectly is it possible to make a particle move by unbalanced internal forces? Is it right @harsharya

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable Internal forces are always balanced. If part A of an object acts on part B of the same object, part B will act on part A with the same force. A force acting on  an object can be unbalanced if it is external and is not countered by another equal external force acting on the object from the opposite direction.

Comment: if the object is made of two different materials then does it hold. Ie metal sphere made by hemispherical half of gold and hemispherical half of copper and attached by blending. Their properties shouldn't be the same note: just asking  not willing to  contradict . @V.F

Comment: @Nobodyrecognizeable The material composition of an object does not matter. This is all based on Newton's laws, which applicable to all materials or combinations of materials.